# Mongodb Aggregate to return data dependent dynamic condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My data has two important fields "success" and "error". I would like to retrieve all the users that have either. However, if a user has both, the "error" should be ignored and I should only see the "success" object. I am having a little trouble expressing this in words. Do not hesitate the request clarifying questions.

The aggregation begins with this match

```
{
        "$and" : [
            {
                "time" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2023-04-23T00:00:00.000+0000")
                }
            },
            {
                "time" : {
                    "$lte" : ISODate("2023-04-25T00:00:00.000+0000")
                }
            },
            {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "type" : "success"
                    },
                    {
                        "type" : "error"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Followed by this Group stage

```
{
    "_id": {
         "name": "$data.agent.name",
         "id": "$data.agent.id",
         "time": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%m-%d-%Y", "date": "$time"}},
         "type": "$type",
    }
}
```

Here are an extract of the results

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Samus Aran",
        "id" : "ID123456",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "success"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Samus Aran",
        "id" : "ID123456",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "error"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "John Doe",
        "id" : "ID654321",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "error"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Jean Moulin",
        "id" : "ID456123",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "success"
    }
}
```

I would like that if an ID number has both a success type and an error type, on the same day, the error should be ignored. Using the above set of results as an example, we should get the following:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Samus Aran",
        "id" : "ID123456",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "success"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "John Doe",
        "id" : "ID654321",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "error"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : {
        "name" : "Jean Moulin",
        "id" : "ID456123",
        "time" : "04-24-2023",
        "type" : "success"
    }
}
```

To be clear, if a member of the result set has both types, only the success type should be returned.
Note: An ID may have multiple success and error types per day. I only need to know if an ID has an error type with no success types that day or (at least 1) just success type. Note sure this would drive the query in anyway but this query will then be added to a go application.

Comment: You can write the condition much shorter: `{ $match: { time: { $gte: ISODate("2023-04-23"), $lte: ISODate("2023-04-25") }, type: { $in: ["success", "error"] } }` - it will also use index if defined on `{time: 1, type: 1}`

Comment: I don't think I understand this completely @WernfriedDomscheit but it seems to only be a shorter syntax or is it a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

One option is replace your `$group` with:

1. Sort so that `success` will be before `error`
2. Group types together to one set
3. Keep only the first type

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {type: -1}},
  {$group: {
      "_id": {
        "name": "$data.agent.name",
        "id": "$data.agent.id",
        "time": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%m-%d-%Y", "date": "$time"}}
      },
      type: {$addToSet: "$type"}
  }},
  {$set: {type: {$first: "$type"}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zatQUsMshEm)